# SQL Server: alter table, how to add SPARSE definition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, alter

I would like alter my table and add `SPARSE` option to all fields that contain a lot of NULL values. What is the right syntax for this `ALTER TABLE` command?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #Foo
(
X INT NULL,
Y INT NULL
)


ALTER TABLE #Foo ALTER COLUMN Y INT  SPARSE NULL 

ALTER TABLE #Foo ALTER COLUMN X INT SPARSE NULL
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in a single ALTER TABLE statement?

Comment: @jrara - No. [The `ALTER TABLE` grammar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) allows you to add multiple columns but only alter one of them for some reason.

Answer (score 14):

The other answers work, but you can also get away with:

```sql
ALTER TABLE #foo ALTER COLUMN bar ADD SPARSE;
```

This way you don't have to look up the column's type or nullability.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE Xtable
ADD myCol int sparse null
```